# What I not writing correctly that I can not display message in the alert/console?

Tags: javascript

I make registration in my app. When I send form into my local server and username in this server already registered serverer return error 400 and response(in my browser/Network/Request file/Response I see):

```
[
    {
        "message": "User with this username already exists",
        "f": "user",
        "val": "uni"
    }
]
```

And I need output this message into alert or console.
And I tried to do it:

```
const er = res[0].message;
console.log('Error',er);
```

but nothing displayed in the console. Only two message in console: `POST http://localhost:3333/api/auth/register 400 (Bad Request) TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined.`

But must displayed only this message:
`User with this username already exists`

Code where I wrote this piece(I comment what which happens in different cases):

```
 onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;   // when the user is unique and there is no error
              const er = res[0].message;       // when I have errror and response error message

               localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);

              console.log('Result!',token);     //display in console token
              console.log('Error',er);          // display response error message

              history.push("/home");

          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });
```

And function api:

```
export const api = async (url, args) => { 
  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}`, {
   ...args,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 " ,
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      ...args.headers,  
    },
  });

 return response.json();    

}
```

What can I change in this code to display an alert or console message:
`User with this username already exists`

What can I change in this code to display an alert or console this `error message`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You haven't provided enough code for us to tell you how to fix your problem. What is the `api` function, for example?

Comment: you will see your error message in catch ```catch(e) {
              console.error(e);
          } ``` if it is 400 error code

Comment: @TapanDave That's actually not the case with the `fetch` API AFAIK, it doesn't throw on an error response. You need to check `response.ok` or `response.status` to see if the request failed. It only throws when you are, for example, offline.

Comment: @Tapan Dave  I need output in console message: ```User with this username already exists```. But now in my console output only: 400 Bad Request

Comment: If the response is an error, do you still have that `token`? If not, then you'd get an error when trying to access the undefined `token` in `res.token.token`.

Comment: @rid When response  is an error I dont have token. Only two message in console:
```POST http://localhost:3333/api/auth/register 400 (Bad Request)```
```TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined```

Comment: First of all, you need to handle success and error response separately using `response.ok`. Otherwise, you will get unexpected messages such as @rid mentioned

Comment: @bytor can you share output of `console.log(res)` after `const res`?

Comment: @Abhishek Jain My output of ```console.log(res)``` after ```const res``` http://i.piccy.info/i9/e9543e1d756b617b79e94dff5fdcd657/1586765085/21930/1372209/Screenshot_5.png

Comment: As your error log states `res[0]` is undefined -> log your whole response to see how it is structured. It is not an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not deface your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify the onSubmit snippet to below and check if this resolves your issue:

```
onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              if(!res.ok){
                  const er = res[0].message;       // when I have errror and response error message
                  console.log('Error',er);          // display response error message
              } else {
              const token = res.token.token;   // when the user is unique and there is no error
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);

              console.log('Result!',token);     //display in console token
              history.push("/home");
             }
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });
```

Comment: Are you still having an `undefined` error as depicted in your screenshot?